# A question on hypercubes and the central limit theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, monte-carlo

I was reading a book on Monte Carlo methods and now I'm trying to make sense of an excercise. At one point they say that according to the central limit theorem most of the points ${\bf x} \in [0,1]^n$ are near the hyperplane $\{{\bf x} \mid \sum_i^n x_i = n/2\}$ which passes through the center of the hypercube. Then, if the distance of some point $\mathbf x$ to the hyperplane is
$$d_h({\bf x}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \bigg |\sum_i^n (x_i - 1/2) \bigg |
$$
we can define a set $B_\epsilon = \{ {\bf x} \in [0,1]^n \mid d_c({\mathbf x}) \leq \epsilon \}$ which has volume nearly $1 - 2\Phi(-\epsilon\sqrt{12n})$, for large $n$.

So, what does $\Phi$ stand for in this statement? Is it the PDF of the standard normal distribution? Also, I would like to know how this approximation of the volume is derived and how is this related to the central limit theorem.

Comment: $\Phi$ is the  CDF of the standard normal distribution: $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\varphi(u)du$ where $\varphi(u)=\exp(-u^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  The CLT comes into play because Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]^n$ is the product of $n$ copies of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and so  the individual components are i.i.d.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you have any references I can check on this subject?

Comment: Any upper-division or graduate level probability text book has a lot to say on this subject; I like Breiman's and Billingsley's.  The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem will do in a pinch.   The overarching trick is to identify volume of a subset of the cube with the probability of the event that a random point in the cube lies in the subset.  This lets you translate your geometry problem into a probability one.